# Jetty always returning 400 status code on Java HttpServlet

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, junit, jetty

I'm currently trying to get a unit test set up for an HttpServlet class I have in Java. However, the Jetty documentation is kind of lacking and I'm a little stuck. I'm fairly certain the contextPath is /hbc as I printed it out using getContextPath() in the servlet. However, I'm not certain what a) the second parameter to the addServlet() method should be and b) what the URI should be.

The status code keeps returning back as 400 and the content is null. I'm not sure if it's because i'm not pointing to the right location (but I would think that would lead to a 404) or if something else is missing.

The servlet has an init(), processRequest(), doGet(), and doPost() method.

Thoughts?

```
public class HBCUnitTests extends TestCase {
    private ServletTester tester;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        tester = new ServletTester();
        tester.setContextPath("/hbc");
        tester.addServlet(HubCommServlet.class, "/");
        tester.start();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        tester.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        HttpTester request = new HttpTester();
        request.setMethod("POST");
        request.setVersion("HTTP/1.1");
        request.setURI("/");

        System.out.println(request.generate());

        HttpTester response = new HttpTester();
        response.parse(tester.getResponses(request.generate()));

        System.out.println(response.getContent());
        System.out.println(response.getURI());
        System.out.println(response.getReason());

        assertEquals(200,response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("<h1>Hello Servlet</h1>",response.getContent());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using JMock to test the servlet.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the second argument to `addServlet()` is the servlet-mapping.

If the contextPath is `/hbc` and your servlet is mapped to `/` then I would expect that you need to request `/hbc/`:

```
HttpTester request = new HttpTester();
...
request.setURI("/hbc/");
```

Comment: So the URI should be the context path + the second parameter to that functions? Also, I'm not sure where the servlet is mapped do. There is nothing special being done in the code mapping-wise, so how could i determine where it is mapped to?

Comment: the second argument to addServlet seems to be identical to a `<servlet-mapping>` in web.xml

Comment: Okay, I've made the context path /hbc, the addSerlvet argument /HubComm (which is what is inside of <servlet-mapping><url-pattern></url-pattern></servlet-mapping>. Should I then manually set the URI to /hbc/HubComm? If so, i'm still getting a 400